# How can I remove JSON brackets and double quotes?

Tags: php, json

I'm doing a log file for a clicks-counter in PHP. The data (date, time, etc.) everytime the user clicks the button are directed in a data.json file. I want to put those data in a logfile.txt but when I use file_get_contents , the brackets and the quotations are also transferred making the logfile harder to understand. Is there a way to not include the brackets and quotations?

```
$txtlog = '../Logfile-'.date('mdY').'.txt';
$mytxt = fopen($txtlog, "a") or die("<br/>Unable to open file!");
fwrite($mytxt, file_get_contents("DATA.json"));
fclose($mytxt);
```

Comment: After reading the file you can run a `json_decode($fileContents)` which will give you a PHP object from the parsed JSON. From there you can include what you want how you want in the log.

Comment: There is no need to remove brackets and quotations. Infact, you should not remove it. You should use `json_decode` to get text decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `json_decode()`.
Using it on what you've got from the file, it will return an array with index "date" and "time". Just iterate on it and you will be able to manage your logs

Answer (score 0):

use this `json_decode("DATA.json")`